# Old Mobile site redundant now main site is responsive

Tags: redirects, pagerank, mobile, responsive-webdesign

I have an old site which has a `mobile.example.com`, I finally got around to updating the main site to a responsive version that means the old mobile site is no longer needed.

However I am not sure if I should keep it or discard it all together, my reasons for keeping it, are:

- has a smaller footprint compared to the main site but generally the same content is available.
- still has traffic on it, a good portion still visit it
- pages have some degree of authority with it being linked by some edu and news sites.

I am afraid it might lose all this if I were to delete it, incidentally redirecting the pages will take forever as it has 100s of pages.

What are the good practices involved and what to do?

Comment: If you can't redirect it, throwing it away would certainly toss out all of its value.    How did you deal with desktop clients that visited it?   Mobile sites are supposed to redirect desktop clients back to the main site.

Comment: It was one way redirection ie. Only mobile visitors were directed not vice versa.

Comment: You may want to consider a phased redirection strategy, 301 redirecting subsections of the mobile site in batches.  Anyone who's bookmarked or frequents the mobile subdomain directly would start being redirected for select pages to your corresponding responsive content on the primary domain.  It'll still take a while to implement redirects, but at least you can prioritize and target select pages/content sections.  Then for lower priority sections, you can have wildcard redirects setup to a corresponding landing page, if no one-to-one match exists or is needed.